# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR [Magento][Ubuntu Server][Saop]

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento, soap, ubuntu-10.04

I have to use magento webservice  to get data remotely from my server(ubuntu  10.04), so i have followed this tuto : http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/magento-api-web-service-work/,

but when I try to execute the method in code igniter Controller :

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('myhostname/soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login('username', '***********');

$customerinfo = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo($sessionId,1);

print_r($customerinfo);
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://hostname.com/api/soap/?wsdl' :
>   Entity 'copy' not defined in
>   /var/www/happyprojects/api/application/controllers/users.php:42 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /var/www/happyprojects/api/application/controllers/users.php(42):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('myhostname', Array) #1 [internal function]:
>   Users->magento_call_get() #2
>   /var/www/happyprojects/api/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /var/www/happyprojects/api/index.php(219):
>   require_once('/var/www/happyp...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/happyprojects/api/application/controllers/users.php on line
>   42

Please can you help really I'm blocked, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved, I had to add just ´www´ to my URL call and this solve the problem, I hope this may help you later.

Answer (score 2):

```
$client = new SoapClient('myhostname/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
```

Add index.php in your SoapClient variable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Adding index.php in your SoapClient variable will resolve the error